# Mysql response with "ok", not getting output in "Result Grid"

Tags: mysql-workbench

While executing query in mysql, am getting message as "OK" instead of output. I have checked preferences, limit rows etc.. everything is fine

Comment: Please, show use the SQL statement you are executing, relevant tables and expected output.

Comment: It's not helpful if you hide your implementation details. Can you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: select b.id, b.entity_id, c.mapping_id, c.file_id, c.category, c.manufacturer, c.brand, c.data_for, c.sales, c.share, c.color
from npd_data c, npd_mapping b
where b.id=c.mapping_id limit 5000;                                                                                                  I gave the above query, if we are using limit clause (only till 5000 we are getting the output) then we are getting the output, or else it is returning with "ok"

Comment: Any leads that why we get this message. I tried restarting my workbench also, it just gives "OK" without giving any row result